# clang compiler says: variable 'ptr' may be uninitialized

Tags: c++, clang++

I compile the following code with clang like this:

```
clang main.cpp -Werror -Wconditional-uninitialized
```

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    bool captureSupported() {
      return true;    // it makes no difference to the compiler if it returns true or false
}

// false - success, true - failure
bool capture(char **ptr) {
  // it makes no difference to the compiler if it is commented out or not
  // *ptr = (char*)"captured";  
  return true;    // it makes no difference to the compiler if it returns true or false
}

void foo() {
  char *ptr;
  bool capture_raw = true;

  if(captureSupported() && (!capture(&ptr)) ) { // compilation warning/error
//  if(true && (!capture(&ptr)) ) {             // no warning/error
//  if(false && (!capture(&ptr)) ) {            // no warning/error
//  if(captureSupported() && (!false) ) {       // no warning/error
//  if(captureSupported() && (!true) ) {        // no warning/error
    capture_raw = false;
  } else {
    printf("cannot capture\n");
  }

 if(capture_raw) {
    ptr = (char*)"raw captured";
  }

  printf("%s", ptr);
}

int main() {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Could anyone please explain it to me why the compilation result is:

```
main.cpp:33:16: error: variable 'ptr' may be uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wconditional-uninitialized]
  printf("%s", ptr);
               ^~~
main.cpp:16:12: note: initialize the variable 'ptr' to silence this warning
  char *ptr;
           ^
            = nullptr
1 error generated.
```

There is no possible path where ptr is uninitialized. Or if the compiler is so smart to figure out that capture() could not have initialized it, why commented out 'ifs' make compiler to be happy?

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast in C++, you should take that as a flag that you're doing something wrong. Even if you have non-constant arrays in your real code, you can still use `const char*` to point to them. Or not use old C-style "strings" (pointer to `char`) at all, and use proper C++ `std::string` objects. And use actual references instead of C-style emulation of pass-by-reference. And don't use `printf` for output.

Comment: @Cy-4AH But `captureSupported` cannot, in the code given but with the assignment uncommented, return `false`, and if I crank up the optimization to -O3 then Clang knows that and knows what it points to (see https://godbolt.org/z/C7YpZa); why does it then still output the warning?.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, How is your answer related to my question? What I showed is just a quick code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: My comment is a *comment* not an answer. And it's about what seems to be bad habits. And one of those bad habits (the C-style casting) can lead to problems. Habits, good or bad, tend to stick so please try avoid the bad habits (like pretending C++ is just C with some extra features) and work on the good habits.

Comment: I'll have to agree that the lecture is kinda useless. The presence of the `captureSupported` func strongly suggests that OP _is not_ trying to capture raw C strings with a `char*` but merely tries to isolate and/or demonstrate the present issue in a MWE with the least complex, human-readable thing, such as e.g. the C string "capture". For which `printf` (or `puts`) is perfectly adequate in order to puke _some output_ onto the console. No need to implement the whole of "Effective Modern C++" in the MWE, _for the sake of doing it_, when it's unrelated to the issue.

Comment: I see pointing out bad practices in comments or even answers as beneficial. Or will we finally stop recommending vectors at every chance we get? That's 95% of the time unrelated to the question. Same goes for smart pointers. Bad practices in MWE could mean it's really an XY problem, or the OP is simply inexperienced and some solid guidance early on can be a huge help to better habits. If the code they write for a MWE is bad, their actual code is also likely bad.

Answer (score 1):

You’re reading the warning the wrong way round.

> variable 'ptr' may be uninitialized when used here

This means the compiler *can not* prove that the variable is initialised before use, not that it *can* prove that it is *not* initialised.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do what the compiler suggests and initialize your variable. *That* will silence the warning. It's a best practice and creates more secure code.

Comment: I don't think that just initializing variable to suppress warning is good idea. What if compiler is right and variable can really be uninitalized? Well, segfault.. That way you create even more insecure code. I would rather recommend deeply analyze the thing and then initialize the variable (without 'just')

Comment: I'm echoing the compiler's own suggestion. You don't initialize a variable to suppress a warning. You do it because it's a secure coding practice.